# Can this integral (of PDE solution) be solved?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations

I study the heat equation from the book, [Heat Conduction, Third Edition](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Heat-Conduction-David-W-Hahn-ebook/dp/B0091994XU).

By using the method of separation of variables for the boundary condition of

$$BC1: \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \Bigg|_{x=0}= 0$$
$$IC: T(x,t=0)=F(x)$$

the following solution is given,

$$T(x,t) = \frac{1}{(4 \pi \alpha t)^{1/2}} \int_{x'=0}^{\infty} F(x')\Bigg\lbrace\exp \left [ -\frac{(x-x')^2}{4 \alpha t}\right ] + \exp \left [ -\frac{(x+x')^2}{4 \alpha t}\right ] \Bigg\rbrace dx'$$

Surprisingly, the section ends with this equation. I wonder if this integration can be generally solved to obtain a more tangible solution for the temperature.

Comment: In general, no. Even more so, you don’t gain anything from the evaluates form that you can’t see from the integral solution.